# Unable to capture exceptions from threads with context manager

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, contextmanager

Target Script

```
from threading import Thread
import instrument
import sys

args=None
def main():
    function1()


def function1():
     with open("help11.txt") as f:
          print(f.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with instrument.FooManager():
        t= Thread(target=main)
        t.start()
        t.join()
```

Context Manager Definition Instrument.py

```
class FooManager(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time, self.fmt_start_time = self.__timings()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(exc_type)
        print(exc_value)
        self.end_time, self.fmt_end_time = self.__timings()
        duration = (self.end_time - self.start_time)
        print("start_time",self.start_time)
        print("end_time",self.end_time)
        print("duration",duration)

    def __timings(self):

       return time.time(),time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z', time.gmtime(time.time()))
```

Actual Output

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 10, in main
    function1(10000000, 1)
  File "test.py", line 14, in function1
    with open("help11.txt") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'help11.txt'

None
None
fmt_start_time 1602782848.645685
end_time 1602782848.6461706
duration 0.0004856586456298828
```

Expected Output

All i want is capture the error somehow using context manager instead i am getting the value as None in exc_type and exc_value or what is the recommended way to capture error raised by threads within context manager

Note: This code is working fine when there are no thread declarations after "with statement"

Comment: There is no error raised by the thread. As the heading "Exception in thread Thread-1:" says, the error is only *inside* the thread. Neither ``t.start()`` nor `` t.join()`` provide a return value or exception of a thread ``t`` to the calling thread. Can you change the implementation of the thread payload, or how the thread is created?

Comment: Can you give me an example based on above context

Answer (score 0):

To propagate exceptions from threads use `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor


def foo():
    raise RuntimeError()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(foo)
    print(future.result())
```